# Managing different JavaFX stages through a signle slass

Tags: java, javafx, callback

I'm writing a simple JavaFX application that has three Stages: `Login`, Register (`Anmeldung`) and Welcome (`Anwendung`). **Sorry for the German namings!**

I have created each Stage and it's Scene in an `App` class and the handling events in a `Controller` class and the designs in fxml files. I need to implement a `MainApp` class which has to manage the communication between `Login`, `Anmeldung` and `Anwendung` windows.

The `MainApp` should initially launch a `Login` window and then in there if the checkbox is selected, the `MainApp` should be notified and order the launch of `Anmeldung` window. After successful registration, the `MainApp` should close the `Anmeldung` window and show the `Login` window again. There, when user logs in, the `MainApp` should again close the `Login` window and order a launch for `Anwendung` window.

[image]

I have done the transition between `Login` and `Anmeldung` windows by modifying the `LoginController`, which shouldn't be done there and has to be accomplished via the `MainApp`.

Additionally the task wants the whole thing to be done with only one `launch(args)`.

**LoginController.java**:

```
package controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import resources.Benutzer;

public class LoginController {

  // private static MainApp mainApp;

  @FXML
  public TextField textFieldUserId;

  @FXML
  public PasswordField passwordFieldPasswort;

  @FXML
  public CheckBox checkBoxNeuAnmeldung;

  @FXML
  public Button buttonEinloggen;

  private boolean neuAnmeldung = false;

  // public void setCallBack(MainApp mainApp) {
  // LoginController.mainApp = mainApp;
  // }

  @FXML
  public void handleButtonEinloggenAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    // Stage stage = (Stage) buttonEinloggen.getScene().getWindow();
    if (neuAnmeldung == false) {
      Benutzer benutzer = new Benutzer(textFieldUserId.getText(),
          passwordFieldPasswort.getText());
      Parent anwendungsScene = FXMLLoader
          .load(getClass().getResource("/design/Anwendung.fxml"));
      Stage anwendungsStage = new Stage();
      ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
      anwendungsStage.setScene(new Scene(anwendungsScene));
      anwendungsStage.setTitle("Anmeldung");
      anwendungsStage.show();
      System.out.println(benutzer);

    }

    // stage.close();
    System.out.println("Eingeloggt!");

  }

  @FXML
  public void handleCheckBoxNeuAnmeldungAction(ActionEvent event)
      throws Exception {
    if (checkBoxNeuAnmeldung.isSelected()) {
      neuAnmeldung = true;
      Parent anmeldungsScene = FXMLLoader
          .load(getClass().getResource("/design/Anmeldung.fxml"));
      Stage anmeldungsStage = new Stage();
      anmeldungsStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
      anmeldungsStage
          .initOwner(((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow());
      anmeldungsStage.setScene(new Scene(anmeldungsScene));
      anmeldungsStage.setTitle("Anmeldung");
      anmeldungsStage.show();

    } else
      neuAnmeldung = false;
    System.out.println("Neu-Anmeldung? " + neuAnmeldung);

  }

}
```

**AnmeldungsController.java:**

```
package controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import resources.Benutzer;

public class AnmeldungsController {

  // private static MainApp mainApp;

  @FXML
  public TextField textFieldUserId;

  @FXML
  public PasswordField passwordFieldPasswort;

  @FXML
  public PasswordField passwordFieldWiederholung;

  @FXML
  public Button buttonAnmelden;

  // public void setCallBack(MainApp mainApp) {
  // AnmeldungsController.mainApp = mainApp;
  // }

  @FXML
  public void handleButtonAnmeldenAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) buttonAnmelden.getScene().getWindow();

    if (passwordFieldPasswort.getText()
        .equals(passwordFieldWiederholung.getText())) {
      Benutzer benutzer = new Benutzer(textFieldUserId.getText(),
          passwordFieldPasswort.getText());
      System.out.println(benutzer);
      System.out.println("Angemeldet!");
      stage.close();

    } else {
      textFieldUserId.setText("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!");
      System.out.println("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!");
      System.out.println(passwordFieldPasswort.getText() + " != "
          + passwordFieldWiederholung.getText());

    }

  }

}
```

**AnwendungsController.java:**

```
package controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AnwendungsController {

  // private static MainApp mainApp;

  @FXML
  public Button buttonSchliessen;

  // public void setCallBack(MainApp mainApp) {
  // AnwendungsController.mainApp = mainApp;
  // }

  @FXML
  public void handleButtonAbbrechenAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) buttonSchliessen.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
    System.out.println("Fenster Geschlossen!");

  }

}
```

**MainApp.java:**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource("/design/Login.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Benutzerverwaltung");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Of course the other aspects of the program like Exceptions and creating/reading/deleting users etc is out of the scope of this question!

Comment: Why do you use a `CheckBox` for the user to determine he wants to go to registration, if the username&password have to be entered once again in the registration window? Usually you'd expect a button or a hyperlink there...

Comment: I'll change it to a button later, but that's not important now...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea that should get you started:

```
public class LoginController {

  private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper loggedIn = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();

  public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty loggedInProperty() {
      return loggedIn.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
  }

  public final boolean isLoggedIn() {
      return loggedInProperty().get();
  }


  @FXML
  public TextField textFieldUserId;

  @FXML
  public PasswordField passwordFieldPasswort;

  @FXML
  public CheckBox checkBoxNeuAnmeldung;

  @FXML
  public Button buttonEinloggen;

  private boolean neuAnmeldung = false;


  @FXML
  public void handleButtonEinloggenAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

    // assuming you verify the login credentials...
    loggedIn.set(true);

    System.out.println("Eingeloggt!");

  }

}
```

and now in your `MainApp` you can do:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource("/design/Login.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    LoginController loginController = loader.getController();

    loginController.loggedInProperty().addListener((obs, wasLoggedIn, isNowLoggedIn) -> {
        if (isNowLoggedIn) {
            // user is now logged in, show welcome screen...
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Benutzerverwaltung");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: I reconstructed my whole application, but thanks, the tips where useful ;)